Diagnose performance issues show Oops! Something went wrong. RPC::DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: context deadline exceeded
I can use （chromium 126）→F12→Lighthouse→Analyze page load→succeful
But I can't use  PageSpeed Insights (zh-TW & ja-JP) → Diagnose performance issues → error
Opps！somthing went wrong。
RPC::DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: context deadline exceeded
The en-US is working
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-chinatimes-com-realtimenews-20240513002336-260408/x5x35rylxt?hl=en-US&form_factor=mobile
The zh-TW is not wokring
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-chinatimes-com-realtimenews-20240513002336-260408/f3ssmp3df0?hl=zh-TW&form_factor=mobile
The ja-JP is not wokring too
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-chinatimes-com-realtimenews-20240513002336-260408/umot14caz6?hl=ja-JP&form_factor=mobile
Is it related to the upgrade of lighthouse on 2024/05/10?
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/release_notes

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
